# ASP.Net RequiredFieldValidator bug with the InitialValue property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I just found out this weird behavior, is this a bug or what am I missing?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="" ID="txtSomething" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ErrorMessage="errormessage" 
    ControlToValidate="txtSomething"
    runat="server"
    Text="(*) Required"
    SetFocusOnError="true"
    EnableClientScript="true"/>
```

With this simple code, validation works correctly, even if I write a string full of white spaces

But if I add the `InitialValue` property like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="lol" ID="txtSomething" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ErrorMessage="errormessage" 
    ControlToValidate="txtSomething"
    runat="server"
    Text="(*) Required"
    SetFocusOnError="true"
    EnableClientScript="true"
    InitialValue="lol"/>
```

Note I added **InitialValue="lol"** and **Text="lol"**

Now if I delete the text **lol** validation is ignored

Why??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look carefully at MSDN description:

> Use this property to specify the initial value of the input control.
>
> Validation fails only if the value of the associated input control
>   matches this InitialValue upon losing focus.

I think it speaks for itself.

Comment: @Jupaol - makes sense to me - you may want to initialize with a default value like *<Username goes here>*.

Comment: But if it's empty it should fail as well... at least expose a flag to get this behavior...

Comment: @Jupaol, you know, you can always create a custom validator yourself :) There are multiple weird things spread across .NET and I guess this is just one of them. Still better than php... :))

Comment: I think, this should be improved in ASP.Net. Not an acceptable behavior at present.

Comment: @Lijo, true, but there are more things that could be improved... Until then the best way is probably to create your own controls that have the behavior you need and expect :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual Studio, you can see that "Solution Explorer/References/System".

Double click and Search, you can see that "RequiredFieldValidator is a class, and InitialValue is a variable "

---

#### There are four test you can do.

No.   TextBox   InitialValue   Igonored
1   lol   lol   Yes
2   lol   ""   No
3   ""   lol   No
4   ""   ""   Yes

---

Since that you use InitialValue to compare TextBox's value.